# O que significa o comando -n no git

Tags: git

Me passaram um comando para ver o ultimo commit de um arquivo que foi deletado, sei o que significa todos os subcomando mas não sei o que significa o comando **-n**, veja o exemplo do comando abaixo:

```
log --diff-filter=D --name-status -n 1 -- lib/docs/index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O subcomando `-n` no `git log` é a forma reduzida para `number` e mostrará a saída com um número definido de commits dado após o `-n`

Fonte: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: Juro que olhei antes nessa documentação e não achei a definição, agora que você explicou e passou o link fui la e achei... Muito obrigado, está correto !

Comment: Acontece hehehe.